# Why do we need to make a distributional assumption on the innovations $(\varepsilon_{t})_{t}$

Tags: regression, time-series, normal-distribution, forecasting

Why do we need to make a distributional assumptions on the innovations/white noise $(\varepsilon_{t})_{t}$ for linear forecasting of a time series $(y_{t})_{t}$. In a lecture, we introduced a white noise process $(\varepsilon_{t})_{t}$ as a process that is of mean $0$, constant variance $\sigma^{2}$ and pairwise uncorrelated between white noise terms.

There are of course 'stricter' white noise assumptions, such as the variates $(\varepsilon_{t})_{t}$ also being IID or furthermore that the variates $(\varepsilon_{t})_{t}$ follow a normal distribution.

It was stated in a lecture that in order to do meaningful forecasting, we need to assume some distributional properties of the variates. My question is why?

My naive view would be that, forecasting under the assumption that $(\varepsilon_{t})_{t}$ is not normal would mean that we cannot conduct 'typical' statistical tests on estimators/forecasts $\hat{y}_{t}$ since it does not necessarily follow a t-distribution since $(\varepsilon_{t})_{t}$ is non-normal. Is this basically, the idea behind the statement? Or am I missing something more important

Comment: When you make  forecast, you commonly include error bounds. If you assume the distribution is a lognormal distribution, you could use the .05 and .95 quantiles of the estimated lognormal distribution to obtain prediction limits.  These would differ greatly from the .05 and ,95 quantiles of an estimated normal distribution, even when the same data are used to estimate the model. Prediction intervals, unlike confidence intervals for the mean, are extremely sensitive to the choice of a distribution. This is true because the Central Limit Theorem applies in the latter case but not the former.

Answer (score 0):

To do the forecasting, you need to decide the parameters of your model because you do forecasting using the model.

And the model paramters are usually decided by maximum likelihood estimation(MLE). To do the MLE, you need to assume a distribution on the residuals($\varepsilon_t$) because likelihood is calculated from the probability distribution. And we cannot calculate the likelihood if we don't know the distribution of residual.

And it's also make sense to assume residuals are white noise. Because if your model is good, it should explain as much information as possible. And when the residuals are white noise, it means there is no more information to extract.